# É possível alterar o nome de uma posição do JSON usando JavaScript ou jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho esse JSON:

```
[{ id: 1, total: 50.00 }, { id: 2, total: 70.00 }]
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar o nome de 'total' para 'preco' usando JavaScript ou jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode fazer isso facilmente usando a função [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
let json = '[{ "id": 1, "total": 50.00 }, { "id": 2, "total": 70.00 }]';
let array = JSON.parse(json);

let novoArray = array.map(function(item){
  return { id: item.id, preco: item.total };
});

console.log(novoArray);
```

Também pode manter a propriedade original. Isso evita de ter que copiar todas as propriedades dentro da função.

```js
let json = '[{ "id": 1, "total": 50.00 }, { "id": 2, "total": 70.00 }]';
let array = JSON.parse(json);

let novoArray = array.map(function(item){
  item.preco = item.total;
  return item;
});

console.log(novoArray);
```

Comment: +1 @LINQ boa solução

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não sei se seria a melhor forma de fazer mas você poderia transformar em string, trocar, em seguida transformar em JSON de novo. Algo assim:

```js
var json = [{ id: 1, total: 50.00 }, { id: 2, total: 70.00 }];
var string = JSON.stringify(json);
string = string.replace(/\"total\":/g, "\"preco\":");
json = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(json);
```